# PHP - Show special characters

Tags: javascript, php, alertify

Snippet to allow user input

```
//fetch user input and pass it in URL
alertify.prompt("Please enter note/remarks for this Form (optional):", function (e,value) {
    if (e) {
               alertify.success("Form has been submitted");
               $.post(SITE_URL+"someController/someAction",$("#frm_submit").serialize()+ "&user_id="+user_id+"&comment="+value, function( data ) {
           });

    }else{
       alertify.error("Your Form is not submitted");
    }
});
```

User Input: **My Project Google R&D for every googler**

When form is post the input is not complete and shows like below

`echo $_POST['comment']` prints **My Project Google R**

Here if user inputs special characters like `&` as in comment, it breaks the input

Tried using `htmlentities($_POST['comment'])` and `htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` but not working.

How could I allow user to input special characters ?

P.S : I am not saving this value in Database

Comment: It breaks the url in the javascript, so before the post.

Answer (score 1):

As Daan Suggested, `&` breaks the URL in javascript. Pls find updated snippet that worked for me

```
//fetch user input and pass it in URL
alertify.prompt("Please enter note/remarks for this Form (optional):", function (e,value) {
    if (e) {

               alertify.success("Form has been submitted");

               //encodes special characters in user comment
               var comment = encodeURIComponent(value);

               $.post(SITE_URL+"someController/someAction",$("#frm_submit").serialize()+ "&user_id="+user_id+"&comment="+comment, function( data ) {
           });

    }else{
       alertify.error("Your Form is not submitted");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use post parameters to send your data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: your_url,
  data: { user_id: user_id, comment: value } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stripslashes($_POST['comment'])
```